# Ignoring exception in on_message in pycharm using discord.py

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

When I type "!hello" in my discord server my bot should say "Hello (author)"
But when i run the command this error comes up

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leo\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/untitled/Discord-bot.py", line 16, in on_message
    await message.channel.send('Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message))
AttributeError: 'Channel' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I dont know what to do and other things on this website dont do the same thing I did. Heres My Script:

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('/Hi'):
            await message.channel.send('Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message))

client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKENWENTHERE')
```

Comment: Hi, I copy-pasted your code and tried it and it worked for me. Are you sure that your discord library version is up-to-date?

Comment: Yeah this seems like it should work. You've installed the module using `pip3 install discord.py`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out i was using discord.py version 0.64! Thanks both @Vate and @MLarionv !